# NetBeans, Maven, Felix, OSGI: Unable to resolve missing requirement

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, osgi, apache-felix

I have isolated an issue I am having with trying to build an OSGi bundle with a dependency using the Maven OSGi Bundle project template in NetBeans 8.2. I have Apache Felix integrated as the OSGi runtime container.

I have uploaded a [ZIP file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sy2xqt6bkcg6l55/OSGi.zip?dl=0) that contains 2 Maven OSGi bundle projects: **FirstModule** and **SecondModule**. The latter has a dependency on the former. Both of the projects compile inside of the NetBeans IDE and I can run the **FirstModule** project with no problems - it outputs the required message in the console.

However, when I try to run the **SecondModule** project, I am presented with this error:

> main:
>
> [propertyfile] Updating property file:
> C:\Source\OSGi\SecondModule\target\run.properties
>
> [java] org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.slade.osgi.SecondModule [3]: Unable to resolve 3.0:
> **missing requirement [3.0] osgi.wiring.package;
> (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.slade.osgi.firstmodule)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))**
>
> [java]    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3826)
>
> [java]    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)
>
> [java]    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)
>
> [java]    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:295)
>
> [java]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I've highlighted the part of the message that indicates the issue. From reading up on answers here on StackOverflow as well as elsewhere on the internet, I have come to understand that the issue is that the **FirstModule** bundle hasn't been installed and started within the Felix OSGi container when the **SecondModule** is selected to run. I have confirmed this issue by installing both bundles into a Karaf instance manually. When the **FirstModule** bundle is not installed in Karaf, then the **SecondModule** bundle throws that error. When the **FirstModule** bundle is installed in Karaf, then the **SecondModule** bundle works as expected (only inside of Karaf).

So this leads me to believe that I need to somehow install this dependency into Felix at runtime. However, I do not know how to do that. I would have expected that if the dependency was set to "Provided" or "Runtime" that Felix would look in the local Maven repository that **FirstModule** has been installed into at build/runtime and resolve the dependency automatically. But this does not appear to be the case.

Can anyone provide any further explanations or possible solutions to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you plan on using plain vanilla Felix, have you checked out [OBR](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-osgi-bundle-repository.html)? If you intend to use Karaf, then you may want to look at Karaf's [feature repository](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_feature_and_resolver) to declare bundle dependencies.

Comment: @Ralf Felix is just what came pre-integrated with NetBeans. Karaf is what I will be using in Production. I have wondered if there is a way of replacing Felix integration in NetBeans with Karaf?

Comment: I don't know NetBeans. I deploy into Karaf during development and use Karaf's `bundle:watch` command to shorten code-deploy-debug cycles, debugging my bundles deployed in Karaf.

Comment: @Ralf What IDE do you use? Are you able to debug the code?

Comment: I use Eclipse. But which IDE you use should not matter. Every IDE that deserves that name can attach a debugger to a remote Java process. So yes, I am able to debug the code running in Karaf.

Comment: @Ralf I will take a look at attaching to my running code in Karaf as an alternate approach. Cheers

Comment: Felix doesn't know anything about the Maven repository of course. Maven is a build tool, Felix is a runtime implementation of OSGi. So the answer for "how do I install the FirstModule bundle" would be: "the same way you installed the SecondModule bundle".

Comment: @NeilBartlett The SecondModule bundle is installed as part of the run command: `mvn clean install`. But this only installs the SecondModule when that is what I am running and I don't see the option to customise this command to run a separate `install` command explicitly for the FirstModule (or any 3rd party dependencies)

Comment: @SamuelSlade No I didn't ask how you installed the bundle into your Maven repository. Again you are talking about build time rather than runtime. I want to know how SecondModule gets installed into the OSGi framework. That is... how do you even run OSGi??

Comment: @NeilBartlett When attempting to run in the IDE, I use the default configuration defined in the `pom.xml` file, which appears to be the `maven-antrun-plugin`. So I run no custom commands here. There is an example of it in the ZIP file. I don't know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: @SamuelSlade I have looked inside the zip but I can't follow what the POM is doing. I have never understood why people want to write 150 lines of XML rather than just `java -jar felix.jar`...